# The following code is not running?

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll

i want to scroll down when i ckick button down

```
<button class="luka" id="down">
click me
</button>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#down').click(function() {
    $(body, html).animate({scrollTop:1000},"50");
  )};
)};
```

[image: i want to scroll down when i click button]

Comment: You need to explain what exactly is not.working.. with so less details.. all I can say is jQuery lib might be missing

Comment: When you were asking your question, there was a big orange **How to Format** box to the right of the text area with useful information in it. There was also an entire toolbar of formatting aids. And a **[?]** button giving formatting help. *And* a preview area located between the text area and the Post Your Question button (so that you'd have to scroll past it to find the button, to encourage you to look at it) showing what your post would look like when posted. Making your post clear, and demonstrating that you took the time to do so, improves your chances of getting good answers.

Comment: Looks like a syntax error, unless you've defined variables called `body` and `html` somewhere.  Unsurprisingly, your browser's debugging console is telling you this same information.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: you need to show the css as well so that one can know where you have applied height and all those things.

Comment: Make jsfiddle or something don't make a screen shot.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/lukicha47/rphp5h97/ jsfiffle

Answer (score 0):

You have some syntax error. Please check it out. Here is the correct code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#down').click(function() {
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:100},"50"); 
    });
});
```

Comment: It works. You should have included jquery library. That's it. https://jsfiddle.net/rphp5h97/2/

Comment: As I said before you should include jquery library here http://joxi.ru/xAeDyGbspMxpo2 (here is the library https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js)  and everything works fine  https://jsfiddle.net/3t20a1e2/2/